# Password strength detector in C doesn't work

Tags: c

The password needs a letter and a number. Here's the code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char password;

    printf("Please enter a password.\n");
    scanf("%c", &password);

    if ((isalpha (password) && isdigit(password))){
        printf("Your password is strong!\n");
    } else {
    printf("Your password is weak!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I compile it, it always prints "Your password is weak" even when I type in both characters and numbers. What's wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the question? As noted in the answer by @JonathonReinhart a test will always fail for one character - it can't be a letter and a digit at the same time. Explain more precisely what you want to achieve in English rather than in C.

Comment: Your application just takes the first character entered (`scanf("%c"`) and checks, if that character `isalpha()` AND `isdigit()`. I guess you want to modify your application to read the whole password entered and check, if there is at least one letter and one number.

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This feels like a request to debug a homework assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only reading a single character from the user:

```
char password;

printf("Please enter a password.\n");
scanf("%c", &password);
```

Since that single character cannot be both a digit *and* a letter, the first conditional always fails.

You need to read the entire *string* from the user. Then, use a loop to iterate over every character in the string to check the presence of the various types of characters you require. The functions from `ctype.h` take a single character, not a string -- it would fail to compile if you tried to pass them a char array or pointer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The functions `isalpha` and `isdigit` operate on single characters, not char arrays.

Answer (score 1):

`%c` reads only single character. `%s` is used to read string. You need to change password to array and read string. You can split each character in array and see if array contains both character and number.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't perfect to get the strength of the password. You need to define more password characteristics. I've developed such a code which you need to fulfill some condition. They are:

- The password should be minimum length of 8 digits.
- It should contain at least one uppercase and one lowercase letter.

The code is below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
char arr[15];int count=0,i;int lower=0,upper=0;int ck=0;
gets(arr);

for(i=0;arr[i]!='\0';i++){
    count++;
}

for(i=0;arr[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(isupper(arr[i])){
            upper++;
        }
}

for(i=0;arr[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(islower(arr[i])){
            lower++;
        }

}
for(i=0;arr[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(isspace(arr[i])){
            ck=0;
            break;
        }

}

if(count>=8&&upper>=1&&lower>=1){

        ck=1;
}
else{
    ck=0;
}


if(ck==1)
    printf("strong password");
else if(ck==0)
    printf("weak password");

}
```

Hope this will help... :)